# My teamviewer does not show ID in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I installed teamviewer from terminal by following this guideline ; [link](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/363-How-do-I-install-TeamViewer-on-my-Linux-distribution.aspx)

But if I run `teamviewer --info` (with sudo or not) it shows

```
 TeamViewer                      9.0.32150 

 teamviewerd status              teamviewerd start/running, process 2639 

 TeamViewer ID:                   
Try restarting the TeamViewer daemon (e.g. teamviewer --daemon restart)
```

As the warning suggests I restarted teamviewer but the problem is still exist.

Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Same problem in CentOS 6

Comment: This question is almost a year old.  It has some diagnostic advice and a speculative solution posted as answers.  Can you update the status?  Did you solve it (in which case can you post your solution as an answer)?  Was it overtaken by events and no longer an issue (if it's no longer reproducible or solutions can't be tested, the question should probably be closed)?  Are you still looking for a solution?  Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Try setting your password first. `teamviewer --passwd newPassword`. I encountered the same issue, it wasn't until after I set a password that `teamviewer -info` showed me an ID. Perhaps it was coincidence.

Comment: Nathan, I tried many things, even reinstalled different versions of TeamViewer. This is what finally worked. Bit odd though. But works :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be due to several reason. Please check the log for further information using the below command

```
grep -o "id=[0-9]*" /var/log/teamviewer/TeamViewer8_Logfile.log
```

If you are having any permission issue, then just execute the below command

```
grep -Ro "id=[0-9]*" /var/log/teamviewer/TeamViewer8_Logfile.log
```